# REWRITE RULE reacts strange

Tags: apache, redirect, url-rewriting

I have the following

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$          https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^gl/(.*)/$      gl/index.php?nav=gl&d=$1 [NC,L]
```

this makes that for example a request to

```
https://www.example.com/gl/de/
```

is redirected to

```
https://www.example.com/gl/index.php?nav=gl&d=de
```

so far so good.
 Now I want to redirect

```
https://www.example.com/gl/de/?var=val
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/gl/index.php?nav=gl&d=de&var=val
```

can you help please ?

Comment: You are looking for the `QSA` flag.

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa